# OpenXML - Excel file is not saving

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm trying to edit an excel spreadsheet using OpenXML and then upload it into a website. The problem is: I save the excel after the update and if I open the excel file the data is changed. But when I try to do the upload, the website says that the sheet is empty (if I manually open the spreadsheet and click Ctrl + S and try to upload, the upload works fine.) So my guess is that my program is not correctly saving the file. Anyone knows why?

Here is my code:

UpdateCell Method:

```
    String docName = "C:\\Temp\\MyFile.xlsx";
    public void UpdateCell(string text,
    uint rowIndex, string columnName)
    {
        // Open the document for editing.
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet =
                 SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, true))
        {
            WorkbookPart wbPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart =  wbPart.WorksheetParts.First();

            if (worksheetPart != null)
            {
                Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet,
                                         columnName, rowIndex);

                cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
                cell.InlineString = new InlineString(new Text(text.ToString()));
                // Save the worksheet.
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

            }
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            wbPart.Workbook.Save();
            spreadSheet.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does your upload code look like?

Comment: I'm doing the upload manually

Comment: Hi Seganfredo, I have had problems with OpenXML and I ended up using a library called EPPlus. I found it extremely easy to work with and there's lots of resource.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Truezplaya! I'll take a look at it